# How to choose a response for interactive prompt during installation from a shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu, wireshark, interactive

I am writing a shell script to install all my required applications on my Ubuntu PC in one shot (while I can take a stroll or do something else). For most applications adding `-y` to the end of the `apt-get install` statement, has worked well to avoid the need for any user involvement. My script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 -y
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install synaptic -y
apt-get install wireshark -y
```

Though I no longer have to worry about `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` or `Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it`, the problem is with `wireshark`, which requires a response to an interactive prompt as shown below:

[image: Wireshark prompt]

How can I avoid this mandatory intervention?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Configure the *debconf* database:

```bsh
echo "wireshark-common wireshark-common/install-setuid boolean true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Then, install *Wireshark*:

```bsh
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install wireshark
```

You might also want to suppress the output of *apt-get*. In that case:

```bsh
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install wireshark > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

The apt/dpkg system has the ability to provide un-attended or non-interactive installs.

This involves setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable to `noninteractive` and using `-y` flag. For example:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -y install [packagename]
```

If you get errors, you may need to set the `q` option to more strongly convince `dpkg` you are in fact doing a non-interactive install: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]`.

In some cases it might just be easier to follow the prompts for some of the packages you install later in that same script/shell process, in that case you would want to un-export the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable:

```
unset DEBIAN_FRONTEND
```

For pre-setting of configuration options its useful to have `debconf-utils` installed, which will avail the command `debconf-get-selections`:

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
```

#### Resources you might find useful

- [Explanation of the debconf "seeding" mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20693661/4668401)
- [debconf "overview" manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/debconf.7.html)

Comment: And if you only need the setting for one command, don't export it; just set it for the one command: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install [packagename]`

Comment: @Wildcard ah ok, , I'm just trying your "set variable for only one command" syntax, but this command `fruit=apple echo $fruit` doesn't echo "apple", it echo's `""` (empty) do you know why?

Comment: That could make a great question in its own right.  But briefly, it's because parameter expansion is done by the shell, and the "fruit" variable is not a shell variable; it's only an environment variable within the environment of the "echo" command.  Compare: `fruit=apple; bash -c 'echo $fruit'` with `fruit=apple bash -c 'echo $fruit'` with `fruit=apple; echo $fruit` with `fruit=apple echo $fruit`.

Comment: If that's not clear, please write a question and link to it from here; I'd love to expand on that in a full answer.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard Its not clear to me: it would be great if you could explain:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367998/why-doesnt-bash-expand-this-variable-when-i-prefix-a-command-with-a-one-time-v

Comment: @Wildcard, @the_velour_fog so, if I want to respond with a "Yes" in the above screens, `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true apt-get install wireshark -y` should do the trick for me?