# Why doesn't bash expand this variable when I prefix a command with a "one time variable assignment"

Tags: bash, variable

If I run this bash command and prefix the statement, so that the variable `fruit` should exist, but only for the duration of this command:

```
$ fruit=apple echo $fruit

$
```

The result is an empty line. why?

To quote a comment from wildcard on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367866/how-to-choose-a-response-for-interactive-prompt-during-installation-from-a-shell/367979?noredirect=1#comment653808_367979):

> parameter expansion is done by the shell, and the "fruit" variable is
>   not a shell variable; it's only an environment variable within the
>   environment of the "echo" command

An environment variable is still a variable, so surely this should still be available to the echo command?

Comment: `fruit=apple; echo $fruit`

Comment: @jasonwryan that was a fast response! but that will set the variable permanently

Comment: @muru This question is not a duplicate of the IFS one. That's a different issue here.

Comment: @jlliagre It's the same issue, same reasons, same corner cases. `foo=var echo $foo` doesn't work for the same reason `IFS` doesn't affect `$PATH` in `IFS=: echo $PATH`  - when `$foo` and `$PATH` is evaluated, `IFS` and `foo` are not yet set to those values. To quote Gilles: "If `some-command` is an external command, `VAR=VALUE some-command` is equivalent to `env VAR=VALUE some-command`" and "Other builtins [...] behave like an external command."

Comment: The questions are different, but Gilles' [response to the other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264642/106525) seems to answer both.

Comment: The questions are the same - we're both asking why an assignment preceding a command didn't take effect during the command's parsing.

Comment: @muru The issues are only loosely similar but the issues root causes are unrelated. The string `$IFS` appears nowhere in the other question while here, the main issue is `$fruit` appears in the command line.

Comment: @jlliagre You and I have a very different understanding of "root cause". The root cause is that when bash is expanding that variable, assignments preceding the command have not yet been evaluated.

Comment: @muru The other question is related to **word splitting** while that one is about **variable expansion**. While both are part of the various tasks the shell parser is performing, I still believe the questions are different. No big deal anyway.

Comment: TL;DR: `$fruit` is expanded when the line is parsed, while `fruit=apple` takes effect when the command is executed.

Comment: @muru, I agree with jiliagre; `IFS` is very much an edge case and this more general case of *assigning environment variables* is a different question from just how to alter word splitting behavior.  You may also want to look at [the discussion that sparked this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367866/how-to-choose-a-response-for-interactive-prompt-during-installation-from-a-shell/367979#comment653792_367979).

Comment: If you all want to endlessly debate whether the question is or is not a dupe, take it to meta where it belongs.

Answer (score 13):

The issue is the current shell is expanding the variable too early; it is not set in its context so the `echo` command doesn't get any argument, i.e. the commands ends up being:

```
$ fruit=apple echo
```

Here is a workaround where the variable doesn't get expanded too early because of the single quotes:

```
$ fruit=apple sh -c 'echo $fruit'
```

Alternatively, you can also use a one line shell script which demonstrates the `fruit` variable is correctly passed to the executed command:

```
$ cat /tmp/echof
echo $fruit
$ /tmp/echof

$ fruit=apple /tmp/echof
apple
$ echo $fruit

$
```

---

<sub>A few comments as this question has sparkled some unexpected controversy and discussions:</sub>

- <sub>The fact the variable `fruit` is already exported or not doesn't affect the behavior, what matters is what the variable value is at the precise moment the shell is expanding it.</sub>

```
$ export fruit=banana
$ fruit=apple echo $fruit
banana
```

- <sub>The fact the `echo` command is a builtin one doesn't affect the OP issue. However, there are cases where using builtins or shell functions with this syntax have unexpected side effects, e.g.:</sub>

```
$ export fruit=banana
$ fruit=apple eval 'echo $fruit'
apple
$ echo $fruit
apple
```

- <sub>While there is a similarity between [the question asked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264635/when-can-i-use-a-temporary-ifs-for-field-splitting) and that one, this is not exactly the same issue. With that other question, the temporary `IFS` variable value is not yet available when the shell **word split** **another** variable `$var` while here, the temporary `fruit` variable value is not yet available when the shell **expands** the **same** variable.</sub>
- <sub>There is also [that other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334578/what-is-this-bash-syntax-somevariable-somevalue-command) where the OP is asking about the significance of the syntax used and more precisely is asking "why does this work?". <s>Here the OP is aware of the significance but reports an unexpected behavior and asks about its cause, i.e. "why doesn't this work?".</s> Ok, after reading more closely the poor screenshot posted on the other question, the same situation is indeed described there (`BAZ=jake echo $BAZ`) so yes, after all this is a duplicate</sub>

Comment: but with other commands like `IFS='' read ` the `$IFS` variable will be "set in its context". Whats not clear to me is why `IFS` is "set" but why `$fruit` is not?

Comment: `fruit` is set too but `echo` has no chance to know you want to display it.

Comment: Ok I think I see. If I run `$ which echo` bash returns `/bin/echo`, but `read` is a builtin. so, would it be true to say that, this "one time" environment variable only becomes available to shell builtins. external child processes that the parent shell forks wont see the variable?

Comment: No, this particular issue is unrelated to the fact `echo` is a builtin. It would happen with a standard command too.

Comment: So in other words, the shell parses it into "set this variable, run this command, with the value of `fruit` expanded", and *then* evaluates the "set this variable" and "run this command" parts.

Comment: @the_velour_fog, the difference between `echo` and `read` is that one takes what it gets from the command line, the other uses `IFS` internally. If you had a command `print_fruit` that used the variable internally, then `fruit=apple print_fruit` would output `apple`. (You can emulate `print_fruit` with a shell script containing `echo "$fruit"`)

Answer (score 12):

To understand this properly, let's first differentiate *shell variables* from *environment variables.*

Environment variables are a property that ALL processes have, whether they utilize them internally or not.  Even `sleep 10` when it's running has environment variables.  Just as all processes have a PID (process identifier), a current working directory (cwd), a PPID (parent PID), an argument list (even if empty)—and so on.  So too do all processes have what's called an "environment," which is inherited from the parent process when it forks.

From a utility author perspective (someone who writes code in C), processes have the ability to set, unset or change environment variables.  However, from a script author perspective, most tools do not offer that facility to their users.  Instead, you use your *shell* to alter the process environment which is then inherited when the command (external binary) you called is executed.  (The environment of your shell itself can be modified and the modification inherited, or you can direct your shell to make the modification after forking but prior to executing the command you called.  Either way, the environment is inherited.  We'll look at both approaches.)

Shell variables are another thing.  Although *within the shell* they behave in the same way, the difference is that mere "shell variables" do not alter or influence the behavior of commands that you call *from* your shell.  In proper terminology the distinction would actually be stated a little bit differently; *exported* shell variables will become part of the environment of tools which you call, whereas shell variables which are *not* exported will not.  However, I find it more helpful for communication to refer to shell variables which are not exported as "shell variables" and shell variables which *are* exported as "environment variables" because they *are* environment variables from the perspective of processes forked from the shell.

---

That's a lot of text.  Let's look at some examples and describe what's happening:

```
$ somevar=myfile
$ ls -l "$somevar"
-rw-r--r--  1 Myname  staff  0 May 29 19:12 myfile
$
```

In this example, `somevar` is just a shell variable, nothing special about it.  Shell **parameter expansion** (see `LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`) occurs *before* the `ls` executable is actually loaded ("exec"ed) and the `ls` command (process) never even *sees* the string "dollar sign s-o-m-e-v-a-r".  It only sees the string "m-y-f-i-l-e", interprets that as the path to a file in the current working directory, and gets and prints information about it.

If we run `export somevar` before the `ls` command, then the fact that `somevar=myfile` will appear in the *environment* of the `ls` process, but that won't affect anything because the `ls` command won't do anything with this variable.  To see an *effect* of an environment variable, we have to choose an environment variable that the process we're calling will actually check for and do something with.

---

bc: Basic Calculator

There may be a better example, but this is one I came up with that's not too complicated.  First you should know that `bc` is basic calculator, and processes and computes mathematical expressions.  (After processing the contents of any input files, it processes its standard input.  I'm not going to use its standard input for my examples; I'll just press Ctrl-D, which will not show in the text snippets below.  Also I'm using `-q` to suppress an introductory message on every invocation.)

The environment variable I will illustrate is described in `man bc`:

```
   BC_ENV_ARGS
      This is another mechanism to get arguments to bc.  The format is
      the  same  as  the  command line arguments.  These arguments are
      processed first, so any files listed in  the  environment  argu-
      ments  are  processed  before  any  command line argument files.
      This allows the user to set up "standard" options and  files  to
      be  processed at every invocation of bc.  The files in the envi-
      ronment variables would typically contain  function  definitions
      for functions the user wants defined every time bc is run.
```

Here goes:

```
$ cat file1
5*5
$ bc -q file1
25
$ cat file2
6*7
8+9+10
$ bc -q file2
42
27
$ bc -q file1 file2
25
42
27
$
```

This is just to show how `bc` works.  In each of these instances I had to press Ctrl-D to signal "end of input" to `bc`.

Now, let's pass an environment variable *directly* to `bc`:

```
$ BC_ENV_ARGS=file1 bc -q file2
25
42
27
$ echo "$BC_ENV_ARGS"

$ bc -q file2
42
27
$
```

Notice that what we put in that variable is *not* visible later from an `echo` command.  By putting the assignment as part of the same command (with no semicolon, either), we put that variable assignment as *part* of the environment of `bc`—it left the shell itself that we are running unaffected.

Now let's set `BC_ENV_ARGS` as a *shell* variable:

```
$ BC_ENV_ARGS=file1
$ echo "$BC_ENV_ARGS"
file1
$ bc -q file2
42
27
$
```

Here you can see that our `echo` command can see the contents, but it's not part of the environment of `bc` so `bc` can't do anything special with it.

Of course if we put the variable itself in `bc`'s argument list we would see something:

```
$ bc -q "$BC_ENV_ARGS"
25
$
```

But here, it is the *shell* expanding the variable, and then `file1` is what actually appears in `bc`'s *argument list.*  So this is still using it as a shell variable, not an environment variable.

Now let's "export" this variable so it's both a shell variable AND an environment variable:

```
$ export BC_ENV_ARGS
$ echo "$BC_ENV_ARGS"
file1
$ bc -q file2
25
42
27
$
```

And here you can see that `file1` is processed before `file2`, even though not mentioned on the command line here.  It's part of the shell's environment and becomes part of `bc`'s environment when you run that process, so the value of this environment variable is *inherited* and affects how `bc` operates.

We can still override this on a per-command basis, even override it to an empty value:

```
$ BC_ENV_ARGS= bc -q file2
42
27
$ echo "$BC_ENV_ARGS"
file1
$ bc -q file2
25 
42
27
$
```

But as you can see, the variable remains set and exported in our shell, visible both to the shell itself and to any later `bc` commands that *don't* override the value.  It will remain this way unless we "unexport" or "unset" it.  I'll do the latter:

```
$ unset BC_ENV_ARGS
$ echo "$BC_ENV_ARGS"

$ bc -q file2
42
27
$
```

---

Another example, involving spawning another shell:

Type the following commands one after another into your shell and consider the results.  See if you can predict the results before running them.

```
# fruit is not set
echo "$fruit"
sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
# fruit is set as a shell variable in the current shell only
fruit=apple
echo "$fruit"
sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
sh -c "echo $fruit" ### NOT advised for use in scripts, for illustration only
# fruit is exported, so it's accessible in current AND new processes
export fruit
echo "$fruit"
sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
echo '$fruit' ### I threw this in to make sure you're not confused on quoting
# fruit is unset again
unset fruit
echo "$fruit"
sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
# setting fruit directly in environment of single command but NOT in current shell
fruit=apple sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
echo "$fruit"
fruit=apple echo "$fruit"
# showing current shell is unaffected by directly setting env of single command
fruit=cherry
echo "$fruit"
fruit=apricot sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
echo "$fruit"
sh -c 'echo "$fruit"'
```

And one last one for extra trickiness: Can you predict the output of the following commands run in sequence?  :)

```
fruit=banana
fruit=orange sh -c 'fruit=lemon echo "$fruit"; echo "$fruit"; export fruit=peach'
echo "$fruit"
```

---

Please mention in the comments any clarifications desired; I'm sure this could use a few.  But it should hopefully be helpful even just as it is.

Comment: thanks, if Im understnding right, you are saying the processes can distinguish between environment and the shell variables and bc "selects" only shell vars. agreed. but then when you say *To see an effect of an environment variable, we have to choose an environment variable that the process we're calling will actually check for and do something with* well `echo` will use *both* environment and shell variables. so there must be  something else happening before echo is run. if you havent already, I recommend reading Gilles answer I linked to above

Comment: @the_velour_fog not quite.  Shell variables (that have not been exported) are *never seen* by the process you call, at all.  If they're specified with `$` in the command line, they are expanded by the shell as part of parsing the command you typed and the expansion (value) is passed as arguments to the command you call.  So the command (whether `echo` or `bc` or whatever) only sees the expansion.  However, if you set the shell variable `fruit=apple` and then *convert* it to an environment variable (one that will be visible to forked processes), it won't affect commands you call unless (cont'd)

Comment: they *look* for the variable `fruit` in their environment.  I'll add an example with the `sh` command to show this.

Answer (score 4):

Because expansions on the command line take place before variable assignments. [The standard says so](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01):

> When a given simple command is required to be executed, the following ... shall all be performed:
>
> 1. The words that are recognized as variable assignments [...] are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be expanded. [...]
> 3. Redirections shall be performed as described in Redirection.
> 4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded [...] prior to assigning the value.

Note the order: in the first step, assignments are only *saved*, then the other words are expanded, and only in the end do variable assignments take place.

Of course, it's highly likely that standard says so only because it's always been like that, and they just codified the existing behaviour. It doesn't say anything about the history or the reasoning behind it. The shell has to identify words that look like assignments at some point (if only to not take them as part of the command), so I suppose it could work in the other order instead, assign variables first, then expand anything on the command line. (or just do it left-to-right...)

Comment: thanks, if expansions take place before assignments how does the `IFS=. read` work? if that spec was applicable, wouldnt that mean the IFS be taking effect (on word splitting) before the `IFS=.` got assigned?

Comment: @the_velour_fog, there *are* no expansions in `IFS=. read`.  An expansion means `$variablename`.

Comment: @the_velour_fog, `read` only uses `IFS` after the command line is processed, it acts like any command (though it implicitly sees even an unexported `IFS`). If you did something like `vars="a b c"; IFS=. read $vars <<< "1.2.3"; echo $b` (with the default value of `IFS`) you'd get `2`, since `$vars` was word-split with the original `IFS`, but `read` used the one explicitly given to it.